# Updating node, babel, and other packages leads to potential babel loader issue in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, package.json

I have a fairly complicated stack for a react app. We are moving from node 14 to node 16 and looking to update all associated packages. Due to enzyme not supporting anything beyond React 16, this is not changing.

After updating some packages, the app builds and can be run (using start) locally. However, a number of items are not loading - including images. I tried adding in babel/preset-react but that did not change anything. When running with npm start, the following error messages appear which confuse me.

[image]

There is not a /common/error-codes.js nor a foreign-content.js file in my app so I guess that this is part of react build that is no longer being properly imported?

Maybe there is an additional loader that I need?

Package.json is shown

```
{
  "name": "pagebuilder-fusion-features",
  "version": "1.3.12",
  "description": "PageBuilder Fusion features",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build && npm run build-misc",
    "dev": "gulp",
    "format": "prettier './**/*.{js, jsx}' --write",
    "build-misc": "webpack --config ./config/build/dallas-news/misc/webpack.config.js",
    "clean": "node scripts/clean.js",
    "lint": "gulp lint",
    "lint-with-error-on-warning": "gulp lint && gulp throwErrorOnLintWarning",
    "start": "fusion start",
    "start:no-devtool": "node scripts/start",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "circleci_test": "jest --coverage --maxWorkers=4",
    "build:plugins": "sh scripts/build-plugins.sh",
    "watch:plugins": "sh scripts/watch-plugins.sh"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arc-fusion/cli": "^2.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-root-import": "0.0.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.27.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.1.2",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.2",
    "loader-utils": "^3.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^4.7.1",
    "purgecss": "^1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.22"
  },
  "author": "Arc Publishing",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@arc-core-components/content-schema_author-api-v4": "0.1.0-beta.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@dallasnews/components": "^3.0.10-fusionNodeUpdate.1",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/amp-document-boilerplate": "^1.0.6-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-schema_ans-document-v0.6.2": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-schema_ans-feed-v0.6.2": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-source_site-service-v3": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-source_story-feed_author-v4": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-source_story-feed_sections-v4": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/content-source_story-feed_tag-v4": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/feature_article-body": "^1.0.2-alpha.3",
    "@dmn-arc-core-components/tools_mock-ans": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "@imgix/js-core": "^3.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "buffer": "^5.4.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.0.10",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^3.3.0",
    "htmlparser2": "^4.0.0",
    "isemail": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pym.js": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-error-boundary": "^1.2.5",
    "sailthru-client": "^4.0.0",
    "slugify": "^1.6.4",
    "terser": "^4.8.1",
    "thumbor": "^0.1.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "xss": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,scss,md,graphql}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svg.mock.js",
      "^lodash-es$": "lodash"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 0,
        "functions": 0,
        "lines": 0
      }
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "components",
      "mocks",
      "properties"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@dallasnews)/)"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setupTests.js"
  },
  "main": "setupTests.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wapopartners/Skeleton-PageBuilder-Fusion-Features.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wapopartners/Skeleton-PageBuilder-Fusion-Features/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/wapopartners/Skeleton-PageBuilder-Fusion-Features#readme"
}
```

Comment: Node 16 leaves LTS in a month, this isn't the time to be upgrading _to_ it: https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule.

Comment: Well. There's that. I was not aware of that. However, the code base that I am working on is limited by external factors.